# How can I create time series in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create time series in R, but I have problems with it. I have wind speed data from 30.07. to 02.09. on an hourly resolution. On the x-axis should be the date and time and on the y-axis wind speed. I tried this script, but unfortunately it is not working. Can anyone please help me? This is my code:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)



 input1 <- "C:\\Users\\wind_speed.csv"

    wind_speed <- read.csv(input1, sep=";")

    dput(wind_speed)

    library(ggplot2)

    wind_speed$dateasdate <-gsub("\\.", "-", wind_speed$date)

    wind_speed$dateasdate <- dmy(wind_speed$dateasdate)

    wind_speed$date = as.Date(wind_speed$date, format = "%d.%m%.%y")

    time <- strptime(wind_speed$time, format = "%H:%M:%S")

    wind_speed$x <- paste(wind_speed$date,wind_speed$time)

    timee2<- strptime(wind_speed$x, format= "%d.%m.%y %H:%M")

    p <-ggplot(wind_speed, aes(x=x, y=speed)) + geom_point(stat="identity") + 
      geom_line(linetype="dashed") 

print(p)
```

[The time series should look like the image, but with date and time on the x-axis][2]

[My data looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XC4td.png)

This is a sample of my data:

```
head(wind_speed)
        date     time speed
1 27.07.2018 01:00:00   1.3
2 27.07.2018 02:00:00   0.8
3 27.07.2018 03:00:00   1.2
4 27.07.2018 04:00:00   0.6
5 27.07.2018 05:00:00   0.8
6 27.07.2018 06:00:00   1.8
```

Comment: please post some sample input data

Comment: I edited my post and now you can see a sample of my data.

Comment: please try and avoid posting images. We need to type the data if we want to work with it. Instead, please paste data directly in the question and format as code

Comment: I am sorry. Now I paste my data directly in my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -

```
library(xts)
a <- xts(df$speed, order.by=as.POSIXct(paste(df$date,df$time), format="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"))
plot.xts(a)
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working. It says the error: 'order.by' cannot contain 'NA', 'NaN', or 'Inf'. I looked at my data and I don't have any "NA" in my data.

Comment: @User94 thats strange. Worked fine for this sample. Pls double check the NA thing